# Regular expression to replace words in web pages

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, html-parsing, preg-replace

I was looking for a regular expression (php) to find/replace some words in a web page. But, it cant replace words between all html tags, only between: italic <*i*>, bold <**b**> and plain text.

**Example:**

word: "hello" (case insensitive)

```
<a href="#">Hello</a> im a writer that i like to say hello everyday. <b>Hello</b> Spiderman.
```

Replaces: in anchor cant replace, only hello and `< b>Hello< /b>` can be replaced.

I tested some regular expressions but none is working properly:

1) from SMART SEO LINKS (WP plugin)

```
$reg = '/(?!(?:[^<\[]+[>\]]|[^>\]]+<\/a>))\b($word)\b/Imsu';
```

Doesn't work well, sometimes, deletes the content and put the simbol ">"
I made some ​​modifications to this regexp, removing "?!" or "?:" (i dont know whats mean), but stop working.

2) Others I've been tried:

```
$reg = "/<([\w]+)[^>]*>\b('.$word.')\b<\/\1>/Imsu";
$reg = '/<+\s*\/\s\b('.$word.')\b[^>]\/\s>+/I';
```

not replace anything

```
$reg = '/<(\w+)[^>]*>\b('.$name.')\b<\/\1>/Imsu';
```

Sometimes works.

The truth is that im not regexp expert, and I was few days testing, trying to create a new regexp, but not meeting the results that I need.

The fact is that replace will be use in a WP plugin, which sometimes affects the template or others plugins or DOM isnt well created

Anyone have any idea why not work correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Id' use the DOM for this, maybe http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try combination of these patterns

```
$reg = '/(?:<(\w+)[^>]*>)?\bhello\b(?!<\/a>)(<\/\\1>)?/i';
$reg0 = '/<\w[^>]*\bhello\b[^>]*>/Ui';
```

**Example**

```
$word = preg_quote('hello','/'); // to avoid PCRE injection
$str = '<a href="hello.php">Hello</a> I say hello everyday. <b>Hello</b> Spiderman.';
$reg = '/(?:<(\w+)[^>]*>)?\b'.$word.'\b(?!<\/a>)(<\/\\1>)?/i';
$reg0 = '/<\w[^>]*\b'.$word.'\b[^>]*>/Ui';

function handler($m) { return str_replace($GLOBALS["word"],'!X!',$m[0]); }

$str = preg_replace_callback($reg0,'handler',$str); // replace "hello" for say !X! inside tags    
$str = preg_replace($reg,'[deleted]',$str); // delete "hello" elsewhere
$str = str_replace('!X!',$word,$str); // put "hello" inside tag back
print_r($str);
```

**Result**

```
<a href="hello.php">Hello</a> I say [deleted] everyday. [deleted] Spiderman.
```

**Notes to your question**

- *?!* is [look ahead assertion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)
- *?:* is [non-capturing subpattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)
- *U* (big U) is ungreedy matching

**Explanation**

See the link about assertions above: `?<!` for negative lookbehind assertion can not be used to match `<a href="#">`, because it is not fixed length and causes compile error. Therefore I used lookahead assertion `?!` to match `</a>` after hello. The brackets at the beginning and end include any surrounding HTML tag, so everything except following `</a>` assertion is replaced.

The trick to avoid *hello* replacement inside tags is to replace them for some unique string (say `!X!`) then do the original replacement, then replace back the `!X!` for *hello* back. It may not be the best solution, but it works.

**Why your regexps didn't work**

You used `/I` modifier (at the end of your pattern). Modifiers are case-sensitive, `/i` means case-insensitive evaluation, see [the list of modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). I believe the `\b` (word boundary) in your patterns is redundant.

Comment: thats works, but its not really what im looking for. The idea its that only replace:

(1) plain text or text between tags (2)<i>text</i> or (3) <b>text</b>

Your regex replaces the text within anchor:

<a>text that must be not replace</a>

The result i'm looking should be like this:

`<a href="#">Hello</a> im a writer that i like to say [deleted] everyday.`

Comment: Thanks again. I was testing it, but when there is a situation like that `$str = "<a href='http://www.hello.com'>Hello</a> I say hello everyday. <b>Hello</b> Spiderman.";`
The results will be 
`<a href='http://www.[deleted].com'>Hello</a> I say [deleted] everyday. [deleted] Spiderman.`
As you see also makes substitutions within "href", and sure in other attributes on <TAG attributes>, which can be dangerous. What do you think about ? Too hard to solve ?

Comment: @JuanVargasZuljin: Hard enough, but still solvable. See my update and the second paragraph in explanation.

Comment: Perfect. I had to add `\b` to avoid matches like that: `$word ="pro"; $str= "Dirk Wildgruber researchers, professor of neuropsychiatry at Eberhard Karls University of Tübingen"` Match with "professor" and replace to `[delete]fessor`. With `\b` doesnt occur, or at least in my case. Now I'll be doing other tests because not only dont want match between <a> </a>` and attributes, also in others tags, such `<h1></h1>`. I suposse that i'll have to change this part of the regular expression: `(?!<\/a>)(<\/\\1>)?` adding tags. Again thanks, you save me :)

Comment: Correct. just add the negative lookahead sequences `(?!<\/tag1>)(?!<\/tag2>)` as written in the documentation. I am updating my answer with your `\b` suggestion to help others browsing to this problem.